# Publish Project Fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I get the following error when I attempt to publish my project:

```
Error   1   Copying file System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll failed. Could not find file 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'.      0   0   Applications
```

A few points to consider.

- First, this solution has two projects, both reference this dll.
- Everything compiles and everything runs. (i.e. no missing dll's at
  run time).
- This dll and it's package exist in the packages directory for both projects, and all are the correct version.
- I've ensured that there are no references to the wrong version in any of the the web.config or app.config files.
- I have tried several different variations of updating, deleting and reloading all packages for both projects from nuget, and nuget package manager reports no updates at this time.
- This project has been published successfully many times before (most recently was 10 days ago)
- This is in Visual Studio 2013 with current updates

Any ideas on where to look?

(Update - I've also tried deleting and recreating my publish profile without success)

Comment: Have you tried setting `Copy Local = true` for the reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting` (or whichever assembly contains this namespace)?

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought of that, however, Copy Local is set to true.

Comment: MVC 4 project by chance? I've had this happen before and it started with the security update for MVC/.NET 4 that was automatically installed via Windows Update, which bumped versions of MVC DLLs from 4.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.1.

Comment: @Cory, this is a 4.5.1 project, created as a 4.5 project. I did run into that particular problem in other projects, though.

Comment: @lrb. The correct files exist in the file systems in the right places, as far as I can tell. This dll exists in the right place in the packages directory and, oddly enough, VS can find it just fine for compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my csproj file I had two spurious entries:

```
Content Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" 
Content Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting.xml"
```

Deleting these entries fixed the problem with the publish. How or why these existed is a mystery of the sea.